# += operator not a single 'total' sum value

Tags: python

The += output should be a single value of the sum.

Tried this in Anaconda installed on a MacBook Pro and Anaconda on a CentosOS 7 installation. I'm getting the same result. I did have to downgrade Spyder to IPython 7.2.0 from 7.4.0.

```
mysum = 0 
for i in range (7, 10):
    mysum += i
    print (mysum)
```

Output:
    7
    15
    24

"I expect the value to be just 24" not the '7', '15', '24'

```
mysum = 0
for i in range (7, 10):
    mysum += i
    print (mysum)
```

Output:

```
24
```

Comment: Your indentation is faulty.

Comment: Your indentation is unintelligible - and might be faulty.

Comment: Move the indentation of `print (mysum)` as same as `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're having it print the current total for each i. It should look something like this:

```py
mysum = 0
for i in range(7, 10):
    mysum += i
print(mysum)
```